# How to load css file last?

Tags: php, wordpress

How can I load my css file after all other css files have been loaded?

This is my current code:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

$parent_style = 'parent-style'; 

wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . 
'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/roee.css',
    array( $parent_style ),
    wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method with `priority`

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', '999');
```

more details [add_action()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action)

Comment: First of all thank you. Secondly it did not help. Any other advice please?

Comment: This is the right way, but try this `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);`

Comment: I swear it doesn't help either :-)

Comment: @RoeeDo The second solution of @Saleh7 should work, If not, you can load that specific CSS file manually below the `wp_head()` function in the header(by the way, it's not a good practice)

Comment: view source your page and check where your style file is loaded

Comment: It loads right after the current theme file which is loaded way after a lot of other files..